# expect script stopping after some commands

Tags: shell, expect

I have an expect script that is working fine, but it's stopping after some commands.

the script:
    #!/usr/bin/expect

```
eval spawn telnet Proc_m0_s1 8000

expect ">"

send "cd CLI/Processors\r"

expect ">"
send "getprocessorinfo Proc_m0_s5\r"
expect ">"
send "getprocessorinfo Proc_m0_s1\r"
expect ">"
send "getprocessorinfo Proc_m0_s7\r"
expect ">"
send "getprocessorinfo Proc_m0_s3\r"
expect ">"
send "getprocessorinfo Proc_m0_s17\r"
expect ">"
send "getprocessorinfo Proc_m0_s19\r"
expect ">"
send "getprocessorinfo Proc_m1_s5\r"
expect ">"
send "getprocessorinfo Proc_m1_s7\r"
expect ">"
send "getprocessorinfo Proc_m1_s9\r"
expect ">"
send "getprocessorinfo Proc_m1_s11\r"
expect ">"
send "getprocessorinfo Proc_m1_s13\r"
expect ">"
send "getprocessorinfo Proc_m1_s15\r"
expect ">"
send "getprocessorinfo Proc_m1_s17\r"
expect ">"
send "getprocessorinfo Proc_m1_s19\r"
expect ">"
send "getprocessorinfo Proc_m1_s21\r"
expect ">"
send "getprocessorinfo Proc_m1_s23\r"
expect ">"
send "getprocessorinfo Proc_m2_s1\r"
expect ">"
send "exit\r"
```

it's stopping like this:

```
$ /CLI/Processors> getprocessorinfo Proc_m1_s23
```

I've tried removing some commands, but it's always stopping !

Comment: add `exp_internal 1` to the top of the script

Answer (score 0):

Try putting a sleep period between commands

```
Sleep 1
```

It happened to me before and I fixed it by using sleep 1 second between commands

Comment: still not solving my problem, when putting a sleep 1 it stops at "Proc_m1_s21", when putting a sleep 0.5 it stops at "Proc_m1_s23"

Answer (score 0):

Try adding in the start of the script
    set timeout -1

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
set timeout -1
```

It may be reaching the default timeout period and stopping
setting timeout to -1 makes it infinite